# How to get the value of a CSS property using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set a box A to jump to the same x-position as box B. How do I do this? I tried the following but it does not work (the second line):

```
$("#boxa").animate({
   left: $("#boxb").left
}, 1000, function() { });
});
```

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 34, accepted):

either

```
$('#boxB').css('left');
```

or

```
$('#boxB').offset().left;
```

Answer (score 6):

For properties specified in pixels, using:

```
$('#boxB').css('padding-left');
```

gives a string like: '22px'

Maybe it's better to use:

```
parseInt($('#boxB').css('padding-left'), 10);
```

in such cases, which gives a number like 22 .